# Querying JSON db objects from mysql in php

Tags: php, mysql, json

So I've got an app and a really annoying client who changes their mind alot, so I've decided to store some data as JSON objects.

I kind of have a match system where I'm storing the users registerd for a match as a JSON object version of an array of their user ids.

I want to have a display of all the matches that a user is already registered for as one of my filter options so I basically need to see if that user's id is stored in the text type data object.

The two ways I can think to do this are:

1. to query every single match and JSON-decode the objects then use an `in_array` to see if they're in the match (this I did not do).
2. Just use a `LIKE` query to search the JSON text for "[userid]" (which is what I did).

Is there a better way to do something like this?  Like does MySQL have a better built-in function for something like this?

Comment: Why not store the object as a record with a field for each property? Can we see an example of the object? Storing a JSON string in a database and querying for parts of the string is not a good practice.

Comment: Why are you storing json in mysql to begin with ?

Comment: Are you using an ORM?  Which one?

Comment: Im using the json object to store the registered users on a match.  THe match still has an id, and a bunch of other properties.  I could have used a separte table to store registered users for matches based on match ID's but I've been reading up on the practive of storing json txt fields and wanted to try it out.  But different matches allow different total number of entrants so I'd have to have fields set to the max users which would end up empty in most cases.  I realize thats not too bad but it seemed like a good opportunity to try out the json thing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a mistake to try to store your user data in a JSON object within a relational database (such as MySQL). Your database is not object oriented, it is relational. Following the rules of relational databases will serve you well. You would be better off building a good database (DB) structure and conducting accurate MySQL queries.

If you keep your DB in at least the [third normal form](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Third_normal_form), you'll find that you can add and change user properties when your clients change their minds (again... and again... and again...) because less data will be kept in a given table so you can add and alter small tables without huge system-wide effects.

Another option in the DB would be to create a table that has various properties by id, name, and value.

Comment: I agree with Chris, you should revisit your schema design and leave the JSON construction at the app layer by pulling data from your database, not pre-constructed JSON objects.

Comment: im kind of combining them in this instance if you read my comment above.  Could you explain why its a mistake? I'm of the opinion that just because something wasn't supposed to work a certain way doesn't mean that it can't or shouldn't.  However if its a performance thing then I'll abandon this immediately.

Comment: also, if you look at a platform like social engine 4 built on zend framework, it seems like having a tonnnnnnnnnnnn of things on a site being controlled by a thousand tables can really hurt performance.

Comment: It's true that normalization can be expensive in terms of performance, but trying to use a LIKE clause to search through a JSON object within a single field of a DB table is going to be even more expensive. If you're really set on using objects in your database, you might take a look at http://www.odbms.org/

Comment: I'm really only looking to store difficult variables that I can't easily predict as objects that I can interpret with custom coding here or there.  Granted A like clause will cost on performance, but if I target it to say a user ID that has been json encoded, ["user_id"], i can expect limited results.  It would be interesting to see if anyone has actually measured the time it takes to do a Like statement like this per user versus a Join statement that does the same thing.  It really only seems like the only downside performance to this is querying the stored object.

Comment: If you move the user_id into the table then use the JSON object as a means of caching user settings, your system would be fine. Make a table: id (pk), user_id (fk to user table), json_data then grab the field by either the PK or the user_id. At that point you can json_decode from your PHP app. This would be an OK caching mechanism, but it's still not the best way to store data. If you really want JSON storage, try mongodb